# how to mitigate storage has grown to 10TB in GCP instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I have GCP instance.

My Database size was 300GB.

but the instance size was growing to 10TB.

where my remaining size going?

I have running ongoing replication from AWS DMS to GCP .

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your bin logs/wal logs have grown a lot without you noticing it, you can check for this at metrics explorer and check for the detailed storage of your instance. There is no way in GCP to shrink the disk on your own so you will have to either migrate your instance into a new one with an smaller disk or open a ticket to Cloud Support and ask them to shrink your disk once you configure your instance properly

Comment: any way to clean wal logs ?

Comment: You can clean wal logs by reestarting your instance, and you can avoid storing them by dissabling point in time recovery, but your disk will remain at 10TB, you won't be able to shrink it and you will still be billed for those 10Tb